# Remove the execution delay from the Javasript

Tags: javascript

When running the following script on [this page](https://www.etihad.com/en/book/book-with-etihad-guest-miles), there is a delay of the following execution, because when I don't have the window.onload function, the code runs before the page load and I wanted the code to run after the page load.

Is there a different way to execute the following script as soon as the page load and without the delay.

Image: The red arrow points to the element **redemptionsearchslider**

[image]

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 10)
};

function loadAfterTime() {
    document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').nextSibling.click();
    document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: this sounds like an X/Y problem. What is the desired effect you want to see?

Comment: You can execute on page load using `window.addEventListener("load",loadAfterTime)`

Comment: I want the following code to run after the page load

document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').nextSibling.click();
    document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // Your code goes here
});
```

Comment: If that solution worked for you, you should marked it as accepted answer or vote up @Ayaz

Comment: I did @StPaulis but since I am new it just records it but does not show to you... I am getting this message on voting up. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `<script>` tag right after the HTML element `"redemptionsearchslider"`. This way you can execute the code as soon as possible.

Something like this:

```html
<div id="redemptionsearchslider">...</div>

<script>
(function () {
    function loadAfterTime() {
        document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').nextSibling.click();
        document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 10)
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the setTimeout

```
window.addEventListener("load",loadAfterTime);
```

will execute at page load